# Parametros para um executavel no Python

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como faço para passar parâmetros para um arquivo executável no `python`.

eu tenho um script em python que irá chamar um executável e eu preciso passar dois parâmetros para este executável.

Eu consigo chamar o executável com o `os.system` ou `subprocess*`, o que não estou conseguindo é passar os parâmetros, por exemplo com o `subprocess_call` ele chama o executável mas fica esperando passar os parâmetros, apesar de passar os parâmetros na sintaxe.

Um exemplo do que já tentei:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

subprocess.call(["dgTQ0126L028.exe","TQ0126L028.0000","/scratchout/teste_python"])
```

Ele até chama o executável `dgTQ0126L028.exe`, mas não usa os parâmetros que estou passando `TQ0126L028.0000` e `/scratchout/teste_python`

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Comment: python `.exe` ?

Comment: Realmente, você não havia explicado corretamente. Votei para reabrir a pergunta. Mesmo assim, sugiro que a edite e coloque o código que vc já tem (pois ele vai servir de base pra alguém te dar uma resposta). Se possível faça um [mcve] que ilustre a sua dificuldade.

Comment: Leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Tem certeza que não é um problema no `dgTQ0126L028.exe`? (votei para reabrir)

Comment: Ola, acredito que o problema não esteja no executável, pois o programa chama o exec. mas fica esperando os parâmetros e quando eu  passo manualmente os parâmetros ele faz corretamente

Comment: O que vc quer dizer com "o programa chama o exec"? Qual programa, o tal dbg*.exe? Você colocou um print dentro desse programa para verificar se os parâmetros estão de fato sendo recebidos? Se você invoca via linha de comando, os parâmetros são tratados? Concordo com o @GuilhermeNascimento, pois pode ser que o problema não esteja no seu código Python.

Comment: Se você executar no CMD assim `c:\pasta> dgTQ0126L028.exe TQ0126L028.0000 /scratchout/teste_python` o que ocorre?

Comment: Quando eu executo via linha de comando o programa transcorre corretamente. Eu sei que ele esta chamando o executável quando eu uso o os.system e até mesmo o subprocess.check_call, pois ele fica esperando os dois parâmetros que são necessários ( TQ0126L028.0000  e /scratchout/teste_python). Chamar o executável é quando invoco o executável.

Comment: o correto é subprocess.check_call, faça teste com outro .exe, verifique essas barras não estão quebrando o .exe

Comment: Eu fiz um teste aqui (criei um .exe simples em C# que imprime o que recebe da linha de comando) e **não consegui reproduzir o problema** com o seu código exato. Só não voto pra fechar como "não reproduzido" porque não posso mais. Se o seu executável "fica esperando os dois parâmetros", é quase certeza que é ele que está fazendo algo errado. Talvez vc devesse editar (ou abrir uma nova pergunta) focando no código desse executável, pois o seu código em Python tá certinho.

Comment: Problema é do exe e não do código do usuário

Comment: Então por favor façam o seguinte teste:

Programa Fortran:

      program teste

      implicit none

      character(LEN=10):: gribfile, gribfile2

      read(5,'(a)') gribfile
      read(5,'(a)') gribfile2
      
 print*, "ARQUIVO ", gribfile
 print*, "ARQUIVO2 ", gribfile2

      end program teste

Program em Python:
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["teste.exe","TQ0126L028","TQ0213L042",shell=True])




### teste.exe (excutavel do programa fortran)


### TQ0126L028 (Parametro 1)


### TQ0213L042 (Parametro 2)